# JQuery getJson callback not parsing json

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, getjson

I used to be pretty comfortable with using jquery for json, but I'm having an odd issue tonight that I just can't wrap my head around.  JQuery sends the request, the server fills it properly, but then there's no way to pull the data out of the json response.

The server's ASP.MVC and serializing using the JsonResult/Json().

I'm completely baffled by this, thanks for any help you can give!

Here's my function:

```
function LoadAllPhotos(containerSelector, formSelector) {
  //var serial = "{ \"EntryDate\" : \"" + $(formSelector + " .EntryDate").val() + "\", \"OwnerId\": \"" + $(formSelector + " .OwnerId").val() + "\"}";
  var serial = $(formSelector).serializeArray();
  $.getJSON("/journal/json/allphoto", serial, function(data, transportStatus) {
    if (transportStatus == "success") {
      alert(data.Length);
      alert(eval(data).Length);
      for (var key in data) {
        alert(key);
      }
    } else {
      alert("Something bad happened, handle the error.");
    }
  });
}
```

and here's the json response sent by the server

```
["1--e0e43b1c-c48a-4456-bb4a-94ac3bf20512header.png", 
 "1--f4dcf831-dbf9-494b-b3cb-3f517f31667dheader.png", 
 "1--364ff0b9-a91c-4dfb-9bb8-8288b6e5d495header.png", 
 "1--1a4e75ea-4631-4249-afe8-9d39048e749bheader.png",
 "1--55f26351-0575-4b55-8f81-e8924eaaa613header.png"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not sure if this helps but Length needs to be all lower case.

ie:  data.length

Comment: That's it, thanks.  Guess I was just going cross-eyed after a long day.